# Doctrine 2: Can I have one address entity that can be associated with both a company and user entity?

Tags: php, database-design, doctrine, doctrine-orm

How can i set up just one DB table for addresses, and have both company and user entities access it?  Or would I have to set up a separate address table for each?  thx!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just add the same [Many-To-One](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) association to Address on both the User entity and the Company entity.

Comment: I'd like to be able to have the company and users to have multiple addresses, therefore a many to many relationship.  Therefore, should I create both a user_id and company_id in the join table?  Or should I just create a separate join table for user_address and firm_address?

Comment: That is an interesting question. Personally I would go with separate join tables because it will be easier to work with. The many-to-many may end up being a richer relationship than you first realize e.g., users might have different kinds of address like 'billing' and 'home'. That would mean turning the join tables into entities in their own right. This is talked about in the Doctrine documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional (see the note at the bottom of that section)

Comment: thx for your input, I see your point.  One last question though, what if I don't share any addresses between the users and companies, and therefore the addresses would have a many to one relationship?  In this case would it make more sense to have a company_addresses table and a user_addresses table?  Or should I just have one address table and setup a single table inheritance with a type (user or company) as the discriminator column so that i can direct the address to a user or company as the target entity.